# Is the CNS vascularized?

Tags: blood-circulation, central-nervous-system

I was under the impression that the CNS is never penetrated by blood vessels, which explains why one never sees them in histological samples.

However a google search reveals I am wrong. So can someone please tell me what the purpose of Cerebrospinal fluid is?

B) Why one does not find blood vessels in histological slides?